How much improvement does OpenAI o1 achieve from the chain of thought?
https://openai.com/index/learning-to-reason-with-llms/
OpenAI o1 also add more data than the last version of LLM.

Is this not shown by the second figure in the eval section on the link you shared?

@Oxbowerce Main question (I think) is whether all that improvement was solely due to chain-of-thought or other factors (data, model size, parameters, training, etc), and if so how much. It'd be useful to know in case anyone wanna implement CoT in existing OSS LLMs, can they expect similar (breakthrough) improvements? And if so, why haven't we seen any so far (seems like CoT can be implemented purely by system prompts, no?)

This improvement is not "implemented purely by purely system prompts". To quote the page: "reinforcement learning algorithm teaches the model how to think productively using its chain of thought".
